# jQuery Animate and Loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made some simple animation for a website with jQuery inside Joomla!, all seems fine but I have a very strange issue during the loop. Even cells are all fixed dims. inside the loop I. You could check it here http://db.tt/uuD00TKc the issue only happens with Firefox.

The JS code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
function loop() {
    jQuery("#txt1").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#0089BC"
        }, 3000, function() {
        loop();
    });        
    jQuery("#txt1").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFF"
        }, 3000);           

    jQuery("#txt2").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#0089BC"
        }, 9000, function() {
        loop();
    });
    jQuery("#txt2").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFF"
        }, 9000);  

    jQuery("#txt3").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#0089BC"
        }, 6000, function() {
        loop();
    });        
    jQuery("#txt3").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFF"
        }, 6000);           
    }
    loop();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("#img1").hide().fadeIn(3000);
setInterval(function () {        
    jQuery("#img1").fadeOut(3000).fadeIn(3000);
}, 5000);    

jQuery("#img2").hide().fadeIn(9000);
setInterval(function () {        
    jQuery("#img2").fadeOut(9000).fadeIn(9000);
}, 5000);  

jQuery("#img3").hide().fadeIn(6000);
setInterval(function () {        
    jQuery("#img3").fadeOut(6000).fadeIn(6000);
}, 5000);      

});
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="home-mosaico">
<div class="row">
<span class="cell-img" id="img1"><img src="http://www.quatrotd.co.uk/images/home/substation-02.jpg" alt="Substation" title="Substation" /></span>
<span class="cell" id="txt1">Engineering<br />and Construction</span>
<span class="cell-img" id="img2"><img src="http://www.quatrotd.co.uk/images/home/substation-01.jpg" alt="Substation" title="Substation" /></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<span class="cell" id="txt2">Transmission Lines</span>
<span class="cell-img" id="img3"><img src="http://www.quatrotd.co.uk/images/home/transmision_lines-01.jpg" alt="Transmision Lines" title="Transmision Lines" /></span>
<span class="cell" id="txt3">Substations</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
/*** Home mosaico ***/
#home-mosaico {
display: table;
width: 940px;
height: 500px;
}
#home-mosaico .row {
display: table-row;
height: 250px; 
}
#home-mosaico .cell-img {
display: table-cell;
width: 313px;
background-color: #0089BC;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;
line-height: 24px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#ffffff;
}
#home-mosaico .cell {
display: table-cell;
width: 313px;
background-color: #FFF;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;
line-height: 24px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements)

Comment: Please post your `html` structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loop` function looks like it will run into some problems. As soon as the loop function starts, it will keep recursively calling itself instantly putting a large strain on the browser as there isn't even a seconds break between calls.

On top of that, as soon as any of the animations are finished, they will also additionally call the loop function again compounding the first issue. While the animations may stack correctly (one after the other on the elements you told it to animate), there is a huge amount of recursion occurring in that loop function.

An alternative for the loop function but still getting the same effect (animation stacking) might be something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var txt1Animate = function()
    {
        jQuery("#txt1").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#0089BC"
            }, 3000, function(){
            jQuery(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#FFF"
            }, 3000, txt1Animate);
        });
    }
    var txt2Animate = function()
    {
        jQuery("#txt2").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#0089BC"
            }, 9000, function(){
            jQuery(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#FFF"
            }, 9000, txt2Animate);
        });
    }
    var txt3Animate = function()
    {
        jQuery("#txt3").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#0089BC"
            }, 6000, function(){
            jQuery(this).animate({
                backgroundColor: "#FFF"
            }, 6000, txt3Animate);
        });
    }

    txt1Animate();
    txt2Animate();
    txt3Animate();
});
```

This would now correctly wait for the first animation to finish on the element, then do the second and only once the second is complete will it start again. This stops the animation queue from spiraling out of control with 100s to 1000s of animations being queued a second.

Addressing your second part of the question, you are calling `fadeOut` and then straight away calling `fadeIn`. While this should queue that animation, that goes for 12 seconds and then you have it already being called again looped by `setInterval`. This would also create issues in the long term with the queue growing every 10 or so seconds without any chance of finishing.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("#img1").hide().fadeIn(3000);
    var img1Fade = function()
    {
        jQuery("#img1").fadeOut(3000).fadeIn(3000,function()
        {
            setTimeout(img1Fade,5000);
        });
    }

    jQuery("#img2").hide().fadeIn(9000);
    var img2Fade = function()
    {
        jQuery("#img2").fadeOut(9000).fadeIn(9000,function()
        {
            setTimeout(img2Fade,5000);
        });
    }

    jQuery("#img3").hide().fadeIn(6000);
    var img3Fade = function()
    {
        jQuery("#img3").fadeOut(6000).fadeIn(6000,function()
        {
            setTimeout(img3Fade,5000);
        });
    }

    img1Fade();
    img2Fade();
    img3Fade();
});
```

Similar to the other code I provided, this loops on itself in a way that won't have a huge queue of animations at once. It nicely waits for the fade in to finish before running `setTimeout` to loop the function again.

**EDIT**

Picked up one bug in the code I supplied originally, I was using `$` for jQuery however in your code on the site you linked, I required to do `jQuery` instead.

Comment: Your solution is quite good and much more efficient than mine. But I still have that nasty issue with Mozilla. I will keep checking for some broken code. Thanks @Turnej.

Comment: Can you set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code? Link it in the question so we can tweak it on the fly. :)

Comment: I [had a look in my Firefox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13011603/stackoverflow-no-firefox-bug.jpg) but I am not having the same issues as your original post. What version of Firefox are you using? What I have done is change up the HTML and CSS a bit with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuBhy/3/). Instead of using `display:cell` etc, I am just making the items float next to each other. It produces essentially the same result but most importantly, may get around your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try as the problem only happens when online at http://www.quatrotd.co.uk/index.php and in jsFiddle seems ok :)

Comment: Yeah I am encountering the issue in Firefox now. [Here is what I see](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13011603/stackoverflow-firefox-bug-live-site.jpg). I noticed whenever this occurs though, when I hover over the page elements, it fixes itself automatically. To me, it does seem like a Firefox bug however it is something hard to narrow down. Also, I updated my answer as I found a minor bug in my code. The website requires me to use `jQuery` over `$` so that wasn't doing the text fading properly.

Comment: Many thanks... it was driving me mad for the last days. So I will blame Firefox :) Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh to me it looks like you might have an unclosed DIV or some other unclosed tag somewhere.
Every modern browser tries to solve this common mistake but FF does it in an odd way.
Let us know.

Comment: I checked the code and now missing tags. Thanks for your quick reply. Anyway I will recheck it again.